# Angular http post method request with url and no body parameters

Tags: angular, http-post, angular-http

The typescript code should call an POST end point. The end point is just an url with no body parameters. I have tried the http.post() method by providing the just the url and no other parameters.

sample code.

```
let postUrl = "http://hostname:9893/service/fetch/72637"; 

this.http.post(postUrl, {}).map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe( data => {
      console.log("post url: "  + data );
});
```

Error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 message:"Cannot read property 'post' of undefined" stack:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined\n    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/5.chunk.js:222:23)\n    at HTMLTableRowElement.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onclick] (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:6601:39)\n    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:5969:31)\n    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:66347:33)\n    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:5968:36)\n    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:5736:47)\n    at HTMLTableRowElement.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:6031:38)"
__proto__:Error {constructor: , name: "TypeError", message: "", …} constructor:function TypeError() { … }
```

**Update: 

Solution:**

The above code is being used inside the callback, so this context is updated to different context hence http is not available. Binding with this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is being used inside the callback, so this context is updated to different context hence http is not available. Binding with this resolved the issue.